# crystal reports, ReportDocument.printtoprinter() not executing in live code

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I am developing a web application in which crystal reports are being used for Reporting.

**Developing Environment :** MS Visual Studio 2005 (ASP.NET, C#.NET And Crystal Reports)

I'am using the following lines of code

```
ReportDocument objRd=new ReportDocument();
objRd.Load("SomeReport.rpt");
objRd.SetParameterValue(0,"Value");
objRd.PrintOptions.PrinterName="The Printer Connected";
objRd.PrintToPrinter(1,false,0,0);
objRd.Close();
```

The code works fine in debug mode, the printer is getting invoked and i can get a print on the paper.

when the code is **Live(hosted in IIS)** after executing the line **objRd.PrintToPrinter(1,false,0,0);** no further process is going on (to check this i was gone to "Debug -> Attach to Process" in Visual Studio IDE and attached the Browser so that when i am accessing the Hosted website through URL i can get back to IDE and continue in Debug).

Either the system it self not getting hang or the Application.

I can redirect the ReportDocument to Crystal Report Viewer and can convert it to PDF,DOC etc., but i need to print the output directly to the printer.

Please Help me in solving the issue.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

I am really feeling bad now that stackoverflow cannot solve my problem in a week(????).

Recently i tried a method suggested by my friend i.e. giving full access control to the hosted folder. still the issues stands :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the crystal report javascript into live code iis folder. I am not sure extract location of the javascript right now. but search the c drive for crystal report javascript files. without this files you can not access any inbuilt function of crystal reports

Comment: thank you for the replay Saroop. I really felt bad for no replays. Once i found the JS Files i'll include the files in the ASPX file where i'm using the Crystal reports. And Do i need to call any JS Function further?

Comment: @srinivas: You need to add these all files into aspnet_client directory of IIS.Not required to call any JS function.

Comment: The JS files are already in the location "aspnet_client/system_web/../crystalreportwebviewer3/JS/ " and the same files are available in the location "windows/microsoft.net/framework/2.0../crystalreportwebviewer3/JS/" i copied the files from there and pasted to the aspnet_client folder. But the function is still not working.